# How to delete nested Firebase data with Vue.js

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore, vuetify.js

I am attempting to build a Vue.js component that enables deleting of nested Firebase data. My component currently looks like the following:

```
<v-flex v-for="user in users" :key="user.id" xs12 md12>
  <v-layout row wrap>
    <v-flex v-for="newUser in user.gallery" :key="newUser.id" xs12 sm6 md3>
      <v-img :src="newUser.image" />
      <v-btn @click="deleteImg(newUser.id)">x</v-btn>
    </v-flex>
  </v-layout>
</v-flex>
```

This component uses a v-for directive to first loop through all Firebase items returned to the `users` array. The second v-for directive loops through all of the images inside a nested Firebase array called `gallery`. The delete button is intended to target the id of each image (newUser.id) inside the nested `gallery` array. Here is the `deleteImg()` method:

```
    deleteImg (img) {
      db.collection('users').doc(img).delete()
    }
```

When I click the `deleteImg()` button, I get the following handler error:

```
Function CollectionReference.doc() requires its first argument to be of type non-empty string, but it was: undefined
```

How can I adjust the `deleteImg()` handler to properly target images based on id in the nested array? Thanks!

******REVISION******

Here is the full code for a better example of what I am trying to accomplish. Basically, this component is set up to push new input into an array called `events` (which already exists as a document field in Firebase), and then then return those array items in `user.events` to the screen. As you can see in the screenshot below, those inputted items are stored in the events array. Those array items render on the screen just fine. I am attempting to delete those array items, but am not sure how to properly target them. How can I configure the `deleteInput()` method to target those array items?

```
<template>
  <div class="input">
    <input v-model="newInput" />
    <button @click.prevent="addInput()">submit</button>
    <br><br>
    <div v-for="user in users" :key="user.id">
      <div v-for="newUser in user.events" :key="newUser.id">
        <h3>{{ newUser.name }}</h3>
        <button @click="deleteInput(newUser.id)">x</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import firebase from 'firebase'
import { db } from '@/main'
export default {
  name: 'HelloWorld',
  data: () => ({
    newInput: null,
    users: []
  }),
  mounted () {
    this.getData()
  },
  methods: {
    async getData () {
      let snapshot = await db.collection('users').get()
      const users = []
      snapshot.forEach(doc => {
        let appData = doc.data()
        appData.id = doc.id
        users.push(appData)
      })
      this.users = users
    },
    async addInput () {
      let finalInput = this.newInput
      let querySnapshot = await db.collection('users').where('user_id', '==', firebase.auth().currentUser.uid).get()
        querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
          doc.ref.update({'events': firebase.firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion({
            'name': finalInput
          })
        })
      })
      this.newInput = ''
      this.getData()
    },
    deleteInput (item) {
      db.collection('users').doc(item).delete()
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

[image]

Comment: Can you add an example of the `users` array, e.g. few entries.

Comment: Hi Renaud, thank you for responding. Please see the REVISION of the example and screenshot that I added below the original question. I added a screenshot of the FB dashboard to show a few entries in the array, now renamed "events".

Comment: See the answer. Note that somehow, with your "REVISION" you now have two different questions, even if they are linked. IMHO it would have been probably better to ask a new question, for the sake of clarity for future readers.

Answer (score 0):

There are two pieces of code in your question (somehow two linked but different questions): an initial one and one after the REVISION.

Let's first give the answer for the initial question: with your Vue.js component code you need to have a `users` array that looks like:

```
  users: [
    {
      id: 1,
      gallery: [
        { id: 11, image: "http://...image1.jpg" },
        { id: 12, image: "http://...image2.jpg" },
        { id: 13, image: "http://...image3.jpg" }
      ]
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      gallery: [
        { id: 21, image: "http://...image1.jpg" },
        { id: 22, image: "http://...image2.jpg" },
        { id: 23, image: "http://...image3.jpg" }
      ]
    }
  ]
```

It means you have to "construct" your Firestore documents in such a way they return an array with this format.

---

**For the second problem (after the REVISION sub-title):**

You should use the optional second argument of `v-for` to get the index of the current item and call the `deleteInput()` with this `index` value plus the `user.id`, as follows:

```
<div v-for="user in users" :key="user.id">
  <div v-for="(newUser, index) in user.events" :key="newUser.id">
    <h3>{{ newUser.name }}</h3>
    <button @click="deleteInput(user.id, index)">x</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Then in `deleteInput()` you need to

*either*

overwrite the `events` array for the `user` (with id == user.id) with a new `events` array, in which you have deleted the element at position `index`,

*or*

use the [`arrayRemove()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#update_elements_in_an_array) method with the entire object (events, email, name, etc...).

I would opt for the first approach.

Note that depending on your exact use case you may have to do that in a transaction, to be sure the `events` array was not modified between the initial read and the modifciation.

Comment: @JS_is_awesome18 Hi, did you have the time to look at the answer?